# Svelte named slot use always the fallback

Tags: svelte

I created this basic Svelte example following the [official tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/named-slots).

`App.svelte`:

```html
<script>
    import PageWrapper from './PageWrapper.svelte'
</script>

<PageWrapper>
  <div name="cover">
    My cover
  </div>
</PageWrapper>
```

`PageWrapper.svelte`:

```html
The cover is:
<slot name="cover">no cover</slot>
```

The result is always:

```
The cover is: no cover
```

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```html
<div name="cover">
```

Should be:

```html
<div slot="cover">
```